# load urlimage in background quicker

Tags: image, uiimage

I am doing a tutorial where they ask me to load a urlimage in the background to a uitableview. Below is the code I am using and it is loading really slow. is there a code that makes it load faster?

NSOperationQueue* backgroundQue =[[ NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

```
int websiteNumber=0;

for (NSString* website in websites){

    [backgroundQue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSURL* iconURL=[NSURL URLWithString:

        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/favicon.ico", website]];

        NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:iconURL];

        NSData* loadData = [NSURLConnection
                            sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        if(loadData !=nil){
            UIImage* loadImage= [UIImage imageWithData:loadData];

            if(loadImage ==nil){
                return ;
            }

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
                [websiteIcons replaceObjectAtIndex:websiteNumber withObject:loadImage];

                [self.tableView reloadData];

            }];
        }
    }];
    websiteNumber++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the asynchronous style with `NSURLConnection`. That is, implement the delegate methods.

Since it seems you also need to send a whole bunch of requests, it might also be preferable to encapsulate the connection and all related data like the response data into a class whose responsibility is to perform *one* request.

If you make this class a subclass of `NSOperation` you can utilize a `NSOperationQueue` in order to control the number of simultaneously active connections.

However, implementing a correct and reliable connection class might be a challenging undertaking. Thus, you might look for a third party library. Also take a look into the network examples provided by Apple, especially `QHTTPOperation`.

There is a lot more to say in order to make this fast and reliable. But I would suggest to start with an implementation of a class inheriting from `NSObject` - say HTTPRequestOperation -, which implements the two NSURLConnection Delegate protocols. Having a start, cancel, isFinished, isCancelled and isExecuting property/method and a completion block (possibly a property) which will be called when the connection finished, has been cancelled or failed. It looks like a NSOperation subclass - but that is not required. You can later make it a subclass of NSOperation when needed, easily.

The completion block passes an parameter *result* of type `id` -- which is either the body data of the response or an `NSError` object in case the connection failed.
The `cancel` method must be thread-safe -- since this can be invoked from any thread.

For a start, the connection delegate methods shall be scheduled on the main thread. Later you *may* use a dedicated thread - or a `NSOperationQueue`.

I've a simplistic example implementation of this, which has 170 lines of code, and header with 20 lines. Just to give you an idea. ;)